# SlotToPOSIXTime in English Auction Demo

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

in my cabal repl, i'm getting the following error from trying to replicate the week1 demo of Plutus-pioneer-program. I'm also unable to simulate the example scenario in the playground (i can see genesis transaction, but none of the subsequent bids), but I'm hoping the issue lies here:

```
Prelude Ledger.TimeSlot Week01.EnglishAuction> slotToEndPOSIXTime 10

<interactive>:10:20: error:
    • No instance for (Num SlotConfig) arising from the literal ‘10’
    • In the first argument of ‘slotToEndPOSIXTime’, namely ‘10’
      In the expression: slotToEndPOSIXTime 10
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = slotToEndPOSIXTime 10
Prelude Ledger.TimeSlot Week01.EnglishAuction>
```

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs because your code has a number literal (ie `10`) in a code position where a value of type `SlotCOnfig` is expected and the the compiler can't figure out how to convert the literal to a `SlotConfig` (ie "No instance for (Num SlotConfig)").

I would need to see more of the code (possibly all of it) to figure out a solution.

Ah, so the type of `slotToEndPOSIXTime` is:

```
slotToEndPOSIXTime :: SlotConfig -> Slot -> POSIXTime
```

Getting a correct `SlotConfig` value is going to be tricky, but the good news is that `Slot` does have a `Num` instance, so the literal `10` is a valid slot.

Comment: I'm not sure what other context to provide. The complete one-line command was simply that: `slotToEndPOSIXTime 10`

Comment: Five lines, the like to error occurs on and two lines before and after. Also what is the type of the function `slotToEndPOSIXTime` ?

Comment: I expanded the answer I gave above. Basically the problem is that you can calling the `slotToEndPOSIXTime` with one parameter (`10`) when it really needs two parameters; a `SlotConfig` type and then the `10` that you are currently giving it.